# CSV stream containing item name and inventory from client- wishes to display it on product pages. How?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, csv

Client has insisted that instead of giving a set quantity for the various items on the Expression Engine\Expresso ecommerce store, they would maintain it internally on their mainframe and divulge it to the webfront via CSV streams.

Here is an example of one such permutation of the stream:

BAZIK,279,BLACK,149,BREEZY,1192,BUFF,644,BUTTERCREA,931,CLEMENTINE,562,CREAM,1033,HONEYDEW,992,JAVA,21,METAL,845,PISTACHIO,954,QUARRY,1123,RED,1122,STEEL,204,WHITE,234

^ This is for one product type, not all of them. There are multiple streams which compose all of the products listed on the site itself.

So, on the webfront if the page was on this stream's category and the product specified was "Bazik" the number next to the item would be 279.

I'm at a loss on how to approach this. They won't budge on the issue, so how do I get this to work?

@ Foamcow

1. I don't know how to do that and, frankly, I don't have the time to figure it out unfortunately.
2. This makes good sense.
3. This is already being handled, however the result would not be in real time (which further muddies the entire point of this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @foamcow hinted you are going to need to develop something custom for this to work properly as there is nothing built into Store that would allow for this.

IF you are not comfortable with creating this in PHP, there are a couple of places that you might be able to find a developer that would be able to help you out.

1. [Director-ee](http://director-ee.com) is a job posting board that is targeted at the EE community
2. [EE Pro Network](http://ellislab.com/pro-network)
3. You can email the Exp:resso Support team ( support@exp-resso.com ) to see if you can hire them to build this functionality for you or could recommend a developer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on precisely how to do it with Expresso Store but my gut feeling is you'd need to:

1. Write an add-on which would 'get' the CSV data, parse it, and update product stock levels within Expresso Store (I don't know how you would do this).
2. Set up some kind of Cron job to run that add-on periodically (so it updates the stock levels on the site based on the data from the client).
3. Get your client to give you some means to post back updated stock levels when someone purchases a product and have them arrange for their system to update.